# Setting the value of an element changed with Replacewith()

Tags: jquery

I simply want to change the value of an element I changed with replacewith ()

```
thatBox.replaceWith (inputPass);
```

Where input pass is a new element.

Now how do I access this newly created element,

thatBox.x()  doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT searching the whole document for an id?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesnt `inputPass` hold the element already?

Comment: Yeah that was it. (stupid I know.) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> .val() works with form elements like input,textarea,select etc.

you need [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) or [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> .html() or .text() works with p,div,span etc.

---

`inputPass` already hold the element as commented by [acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior)

---

Updated after OP updated question

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

```
thatBox.find('el');//use elementNodeName or id /class  instead of el
```

---

Assign a `id` to the new element added

and search using

```
$('#elID')
```

Comment: I tried x.replaceWith ("newElem") 
then I tried x.remove() 

How do I get this new element without searching for an id.

Comment: I would accept, but I feel like it doesn't answer my question completely.

Comment: I can't assign an id because the element is not unique. That would be a problem.

Comment: @JoeCurcuru assign a class than .